# wxWidgets screenshot leaves most of image blank (transparent)

Tags: screenshot, wxwidgets

I have an application that displays graphs and because the results are often interesting (either due to bugs or intentionally) I wan't an ability to quickly save screenshots. So I made a screenshot button.

I used the code from [wxWidgets forum FAQ](http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?p=32313) but unfortunatelly, this method only saves images on screenshots (applies on fullscreen screenshot as well). Everything else is left transparent.

For some reason, this only happens with **PNG** image export. Exporting as BMP or JPG is just fine.
There must be something wrong with:

```
screenshot.SaveFile("image.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```

I have the PNG procesor loaded in wxWidgets:

```
wxImage::AddHandler(new wxPNGHandler);
```

### Code:

```
  //Create a DC for the main window
   wxClientDC dcScreen(GetParent());

   //Get the size of the screen/DC
   wxCoord screenWidth, screenHeight;
   dcScreen.GetSize(&screenWidth, &screenHeight);

   //Create a Bitmap that will later on hold the screenshot image
   //Note that the Bitmap must have a size big enough to hold the screenshot
   //-1 means using the current default colour depth
   screenshot.Create(screenWidth, screenHeight,-1);

   //Create a memory DC that will be used for actually taking the screenshot
   wxMemoryDC memDC;
   //Tell the memory DC to use our Bitmap
   //all drawing action on the memory DC will go to the Bitmap now
   memDC.SelectObject(screenshot);
   //Blit (in this case copy) the actual screen on the memory DC
   //and thus the Bitmap
   memDC.Blit( 0, //Copy to this X coordinate
            0, //Copy to this Y coordinate
            screenWidth, //Copy this width
            screenHeight, //Copy this height
            &dcScreen, //From where do we copy?
            0, //What's the X offset in the original DC?
            0  //What's the Y offset in the original DC?
         );
   //Select the Bitmap out of the memory DC by selecting a new
   //uninitialized Bitmap
   memDC.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);
```

### Images:

[image: bad]

**Instead of** (made with Alt+PrintSreen in windows):

[image: good]

Comment: Is the window contents actually drawn using wxWidgets in the first place? It doesn't look like any normal wx program to me...

Comment: It may be a litle confusing that the window is just a frame. But it is a regular wxWidgets application with no aditional libraries.
Oh, and it seems that the problem is only caused by PNG export, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the image comes out correctly in BMP but not PNG, the problem is probably due to the transparency, i.e. somehow all the rest of the image must have its alpha channel set to `wxIMAGE_ALPHA_TRANSPARENT`. If this is really the case, then using

```
wxImage image = bmp.ConvertToImage();
image.ClearAlpha();
image.SaveFile("foo.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```

should help, but I still have no idea why would it be transparent in the first place.

If this still happens with wxWidgets 3.0 (currently RC2 is available, final will be next week) and if you can find a simple of reproducing the problem, it would be worth reporting it as a bug.

Comment: Not directly. Passing by `wxImage` is really the simplest way and unless your code is performance critical you shouldn't look any further.

Comment: Removing apha chanell helped only partially - now many parts of imag that contain alpha are a bit broken (I mean boundaries of semitransparent images). [PNG](http://u8.8u.cz/images/screenshots/spektrograf/spektrograf.png) [BMP](http://u8.8u.cz/images/screenshots/spektrograf/spektrograf.bmp)

Comment: *bmp does not have the `clearAlpha` call, that's why it looks fine.

Comment: This is really strange, there is clearly a real alpha channel in your image, but I have no idea where is it coming from. Sorry, but you'd need to provide a SSCCE to allow me to say anything more about this.

Comment: I'll try to make a simpler program that reproduces the issue. This may take a while, but I won't forget :)

Answer (score 0):

You should **initialize** the bitmap to any object like `staticbitmap` before this line:

```
memDC.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);
```